# Using phonegap for mobile video editing application

Tags: android, mobile, video-capture, video-processing, cordova

I am new to mobile development, but have some experience with web app development. I am looking at starting work on a mobile app that involves shooting and editing video on the phone initially for Android and possibly to be extended to other platforms. Phonegap seemed to be an interesting potential way to start both given my realm of familiarity and the potential to port to multiple platforms. I noticed that it has camera an audio recording support on Android. But how much sense does it make to develop something that relies so much on the phone's hardware on something like Phonegap? Would it be so cumbersome and poorly performing to do this way that I should just start from scratch with Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should think of PhoneGap as an easy way to create the UI; anything unusual (like video support) will still have to be written in Java (or whatever the platform's native code is).

The portability of the Java code to a platform like BlackBerry will rely on how much platform specific code you use (and you may not have a choice).

Comment: +1 Take a peek at this PhoneGap blog post on the problems with image capture on Android *alone*: http://www.phonegap.com/2010/06/09/not-all-cameras-are-equal/